# Extracting Symbol line by line

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a question w.r.t extracting a string, with varied len, from individual line breaks that are only demarcated by '|' and spaces. Take a look at the following link

http://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/dynamic/SymDir/nasdaqlisted.txt

I am trying to extract all the company symbols under the first column of the above link. However, I cant think of a logic loop that will do that and store it in a way that is easy for extraction in the future.

I was hoping any pr0s may have an opinion!

EDIT:

Hi I understand some of your reservations. I would be very satisfied with how to think about the solution logically.

Comment: We'd much rather help people who have already given it a try. Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: So you want `AABA` from `AABA|Altaba Inc. - Common Stock|Q|N|N|100|N|N
`??

Comment: I have tried, but the code is way too embarrassing to be on here.

Comment: @DevanshuMisra yes! I tried using beautiful soup to extract the webpage, but I got stuck at moving between lines and extracting the symbols with varied lengths. I used the logic of extracting the first 4 alphabets, but that breaks down at 3 alphabets

Comment: Can you share the link to the page you are trying to extract?

Comment: @ConfusionMatrix Hi its in the question, but here it is again! 
http://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/dynamic/SymDir/nasdaqlisted.txt

Comment: @LowaiisTan please check the answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps your case where you directly scrape data off the text page:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/dynamic/SymDir/nasdaqlisted.txt')
document = response.text.splitlines()

for line in document[1:-1]:      #This helps you skip unnecessary lines
    data = line.split('|')
    symbol = data[0]
    print(symbol)
```

You can skip the first and last line of the `document` since they are not associated with the `symbols` you are looking for. Also, `splitlines` creates a list of lines for you and you can use list index to skip the first and last lines.

Comment: I'll get to reading the python docs more often... and sure thing!!

Comment: @LowaiisTan More than reading the python docs, it is important to practice coding as much as you can. Hackerrank.com is something you should visit if you want better logic building.

Comment: Noted, long way to go, to be a pr00000! and yes, its done!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('nasdaqlisted.txt', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0])

csvFile.close()
```

You just need to change the delimiter to `'|'` and it works out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, will check out this CSV solution in detail!